# How to let users login to my site using SoundCloud

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I want to let users authenticate via SoundCloud for my ASP.NET MVC 4 project. Since there is no .NET SDK, I wrote a custom `OAuth2Client` to handle the authentication. After adding the client to my `AuthConfig.cs`, it appropriately showed up as an option to login. The problem is, when I click on the button to login, it always returns

```
Login Failure.

Unsuccessful login with service.
```

without even asking me to login in SoundCloud. What is the problem? I implemented a very similar client for GitHub and it worked with no problems.

Here is my client:

```
 public class SoundCloudOAuth2Client : OAuth2Client
 {
     private const string ENDUSERAUTHLINK = "https://soundcloud.com/connect";
     private const string TOKENLINK = "https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token";
     private readonly string _clientID;
     private readonly string _clientSecret;

     public SoundCloudOAuth2Client(string clientID, string clientSecret) : base("SoundCloud")
     {
         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientID)) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("clientID");
         }

         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret)) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("clientSecret");
         }

         _clientID = clientID;
         _clientSecret = clientSecret;
     }

     protected override Uri GetServiceLoginUrl(Uri returnUrl)
     {
         StringBuilder serviceUrl = new StringBuilder();
         serviceUrl.Append(ENDUSERAUTHLINK);
         serviceUrl.AppendFormat("?client_id={0}", _clientID);
         serviceUrl.AppendFormat("&response_type={0}", "code");
         serviceUrl.AppendFormat("&scope={0}", "non-expiring");
         serviceUrl.AppendFormat("&redirect_uri={0}", System.Uri.EscapeDataString(returnUrl.ToString()));

         return new Uri(serviceUrl.ToString());
     }

     public override void RequestAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnUrl)
     {
         base.RequestAuthentication(context, returnUrl);
     }

     protected override IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessToken)
     {
         IDictionary<String, String> extraData = new Dictionary<String, String>();

         var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.soundcloud.com/me.json?oauth_token=" + accessToken);
         webRequest.Method = "GET";
         string response = "";
         using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
         {
             using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
             {
                 response = reader.ReadToEnd();
             }
         }

         var json = JObject.Parse(response);
         string id = (string)json["id"];
         string username = (string)json["username"];
         string permalinkUrl = (string)json["permalink_url"];

         extraData = new Dictionary<String, String>
         {
             {"SCAccessToken", accessToken},
             {"username", username}, 
             {"permalinkUrl", permalinkUrl}, 
             {"id", id}                                           
         };

         return extraData;
     }

     protected override string QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
     {
         StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
         postData.AppendFormat("client_id={0}", this._clientID);
         postData.AppendFormat("&redirect_uri={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString()));
         postData.AppendFormat("&client_secret={0}", this._clientSecret);
         postData.AppendFormat("&grant_type={0}", "authorization_code");
         postData.AppendFormat("&code={0}", authorizationCode);

         string response = "";
         string accessToken = "";

         var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(TOKENLINK);    
         webRequest.Method = "POST";
         webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

         using (Stream s = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
         {
             using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
                    sw.Write(postData.ToString());
         }

         using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
         {
             using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
             {
                 response = reader.ReadToEnd();
             }
         }

         var json = JObject.Parse(response);
         accessToken = (string)json["access_token"];

         return accessToken;
     }

     public override AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnPageUrl)
     {    
         string code = context.Request.QueryString["code"];  
         string u = context.Request.Url.ToString();

         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
         {
             return AuthenticationResult.Failed;
         }

         string accessToken = this.QueryAccessToken(returnPageUrl, code);
         if (accessToken == null)
         {
             return AuthenticationResult.Failed;
         }

         IDictionary<string, string> userData = this.GetUserData(accessToken);
         if (userData == null)
         {
             return AuthenticationResult.Failed;
         }

         string id = userData["id"];
         string name;

         if (!userData.TryGetValue("username", out name) && !userData.TryGetValue("name", out name))
         {
             name = id;
         }

         return new AuthenticationResult(
             isSuccessful: true, provider: "SoundCloud", providerUserId: id, userName: name, extraData: userData);
     }
 }
```

and the `AuthConfig.cs`:

```
 public static void RegisterAuth()
 {
     OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new SoundCloudOAuth2Client(
         clientID: MyValues.MyClientID,
         clientSecret: MyValues.MyClientSECRET), 
         displayName: "SoundCloud",
         extraData: null);

     OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new GitHubOAuth2Client(
         appId: MyValues.GITHUBAPPID,
         appSecret: MyValues.GITHUBAPPSECRET), "GitHub", null);

     OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();
     OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterYahooClient();
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues to address, starting with the first function that runs: `GetServiceLoginUrl(Uri returnUrl)`

The `returnUrl`, which is automatically created, contains ampersands, which SoundCloud does not like. You need to strip out the ampersands and ensure the "Redirect URI for Authentication" in your SoundCloud account *exactly* matches what is being sent (querystring and all). Here is an example of what was being sent as the returnURL by default:

```
https://localhost:44301/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?__provider__=SoundCloud&__sid__=blahblahyoursid
```

First step was to remove the `&__sid__` value. You can strip out `sid` value and pass it as the `state` parameter, just in case you ever need it. The new function looks like this:

```
protected override Uri GetServiceLoginUrl(Uri returnUrl)
{
    StringBuilder serviceUrl = new StringBuilder();
    string sid = String.Empty;
    if (returnUrl.ToString().Contains("__sid__"))
    {
        int index = returnUrl.ToString().IndexOf("__sid__") + 8;
        int len = returnUrl.ToString().Length;
        sid = returnUrl.ToString().Substring(index, len - index-1);
    }

    string redirectUri = returnUrl.ToString().Contains('&') ? 
    returnUrl.ToString().Substring(0,returnUrl.ToString().IndexOf("&")) : 
    returnUrl.ToString();
    serviceUrl.Append(ENDUSERAUTHLINK);
    serviceUrl.AppendFormat("?client_id={0}", _clientID);
    serviceUrl.AppendFormat("&response_type={0}", "code");
    serviceUrl.AppendFormat("&scope={0}", "non-expiring");
    serviceUrl.AppendFormat("&state={0}", sid);
    serviceUrl.AppendFormat("&redirect_uri={0}", System.Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectUri));

    return new Uri(serviceUrl.ToString());
}
```

That solves part of the problem. The redirect URI in SoundlCoud now is simply `https://localhost:44301/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?__provider__=SoundCloud`). But trying to authenticate will still return `false`. The next issue to address is in  `AccountController.cs`, specifically:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
```

because in the first line, it tries to return:

```
AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
```

and this doesn't run for my custom `OAuth2Client`, since `VerifyAuthentication` takes different parameters. Fix it by detecting if it is the SoundCloud client and then use the custom VerifyAuthentication:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    AuthenticationResult result;
    var context = this.HttpContext;
    string p = Tools.GetProviderNameFromQueryString(context.Request.QueryString);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p) && p.ToLower() == "soundcloud")
    {
        result = new SoundCloudOAuth2Client(
                clientID: MyValues.SCCLIENTID,
                clientSecret: MyValues.SCCLIENTSECRET).VerifyAuthentication(this.HttpContext, new Uri(String.Format("{0}/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?__provider__=SoundCloud", context.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).ToString())));
    }
    else
    {
        result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    }
```

where

```
public static string GetProviderNameFromQueryString(NameValueCollection queryString)
{
    var result = queryString["__provider__"];
    ///commented out stuff
    return result;
}
```

After that, everything works fine and you can successfully authenticate. You can configure `GetUserData` to get whatever SoundCloud data you want to save and then save it off to your UserProfile or related table. The key part is that `SCAccessToken` because that is what you will need in the future to upload to their account.

Comment: any idea how to get SoundCloud Authentication working with Owin?

Comment: @gldraphael No, sorry. All my recent uses with Sound Cloud auth have been in node.js. Though I would think (hope) that since I wrote this post there would be a package on nuget or something.