# OAuthWebSecurity - Without OpenID

Tags: asp.net, oauth, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

Is it DotNetOpenAuth OAuthWebSecurity only for OpenID Providers?

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new CutomOAuth2Client("ID", "KEY"), "CustomProvider", null);
```

Or could I base my entire authentication in a external OAuth Provider that doesn't implement OpenID?
The scenario is likely if I want to develop a client for facebook but facebook isn't a OpenId provider...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can base your authentication on an external OAuth provider. I just made this SO post: [How to let users login to my site using SoundCloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973017/how-to-authenticate-soundcloud-via-oauth2) detailing how to do a custom `OAuth2Client` based on SoundCloud... though implementing it with a custom GitHub client was much easier for me.

The Facebook OAuth client is built in in VS 2012 - [Using OAuth Providers with MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc), so I don't think you'd need to make a custom client unless there was something it isn't doing that you need.

Other useful reading: [What's the difference between OpenID and OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087031/whats-the-difference-between-openid-and-oauth)

Comment: Thanks Mike! Is it possible to set an authorization header with this approach (instead of use querystring)?

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira I'm not sure. I guess it would depend on the provider.

Comment: FYI https querystring is secure, if that is your concern.